# my post request not working any one correct me here?

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-observable

I am trying to get the data from backend by post. I am trying the following, but getting error not works.

any one correct my post request please?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ServerService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

    headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    postParam = {
        "clientId": "RETAIL",
        "spvParam": {
            "productCode": "PDO",
            "consigneeCountry": "MY",
            "salesOrgRef": "TH61",
            "salesOrgFacilityCode": "THBKK1",
            "salesOrgChnl": "eCommerce",
            "pickUpAcctRef": "5999999108",
            "facilityId": "MYKUL1"
        }
    }

    options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, body:this.postParam });


  getDataByPost(){
    alert('starts');
    let url = `http://mykullstc004004.apis.dhl.com:8003/efoms/getServiceProductV2`;
    this.http.post(url, {}, this.options ).subscribe(res => console.log( 'res', res ));
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerService } from './shared/service/server.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private server:ServerService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.server.getDataByPost();
    }

}
```

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: your body should be the second parameter of ``http.post`` and not inside ``requestOptions``

Comment: @CruelEngine can you update my code? so header is 3rd parameter right? `this.http.post(url, this.postParam, this.options ).subscribe(res => console.log( 'res', res ));`

Comment: yes that should work @3gwebtrain

Comment: @3gwebtrain but `postParam` is not defined in your code , so you may get error again , Please check my answer

Answer (score 3):

as Per @cruelEngine Body should be the second params of your request not the part of requestOptions, So try your code like this :

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerService {
  postParam: any;
  options: any;

  constructor(private http:Http) {

    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'application/json'});

    this.postParam = {
        "clientId": "RETAIL",
        "spvParam": {
            "productCode": "PDO",
            "consigneeCountry": "MY",
            "salesOrgRef": "TH61",
            "salesOrgFacilityCode": "THBKK1",
            "salesOrgChnl": "eCommerce",
            "pickUpAcctRef": "5999999108",
            "facilityId": "MYKUL1"
        }
    }

    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  }

  getDataByPost(){
    alert('starts');
    let url = `http://mykullstc004004.apis.dhl.com:8003/efoms/getServiceProductV2`;
    this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(this.postParam), this.options ).subscribe(res => console.log( 'res', res ));
  }

}
```

Comment: ` headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');` this line underlined in red color

Comment: still the underline exist. sorry i didn't place my code inside of constructor

Comment: @3gwebtrain try new Update with new way of adding `Headers`

Comment: Can you see my update in question. the way I using the service is right?

Comment: No, again you are sending body part within the header one, Try to use my method as in answer, it will work for sure, if not please let me know I'll help you out !!